# Given a service name, get its port number?

Tags: networking, netstat, port, ss

Hi I feel like this is an obvious question but I haven't been able to get a good answer so far. Given the name of the service (which I know running on localhost) is there any networking command line tool like (`netstat`/`ss`) which will tell me what port that service is running at? Ideally something like:

```
$ some-program --service-name='mysql' localhost
'mysql' is running at localhost:3306
```

I feel like there are solutions out there but non of them address it adequately. For example I have considered the following two `ss` commands:

1. `ss -tuln` with output:

```
Netid   State    Recv-Q   Send-Q       Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port   Process
udp     UNCONN   0        0            127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                  0.0.0.0:21119            0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                  0.0.0.0:37766            0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                  0.0.0.0:54399            0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                  0.0.0.0:5353             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                     [::]:51755               [::]:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                     [::]:5353                [::]:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                        *:1716                   *:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        100              127.0.0.1:25               0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        70               127.0.0.1:33060            0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        64                 0.0.0.0:59687            0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        151              127.0.0.1:3306             0.0.0.0:*
```

and

2. `ss -tul` with output:

```
Netid   State    Recv-Q   Send-Q      Local Address:Port         Peer Address:Port   Process
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:36308             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:36570             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0           127.0.0.53%lo:domain            0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:41124             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:21119             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:37766             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:54399             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:mdns              0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                 0.0.0.0:54522             0.0.0.0:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                    [::]:51755                [::]:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                    [::]:mdns                 [::]:*
udp     UNCONN   0        0                       *:1716                    *:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        100             127.0.0.1:smtp              0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        70              127.0.0.1:33060             0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        64                0.0.0.0:59687             0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        151             127.0.0.1:mysql             0.0.0.0:*
```

The first command's output lists the port numbers that are listening while the second command's output is able to resolve them to the services running at the ports. But I can't somehow "combine" the two outputs where I can have the port number mapped to the service running, side by side. For example the rows:

```
tcp     LISTEN   0        151             127.0.0.1:mysql             0.0.0.0:*
```

and

```
tcp     LISTEN   0        151              127.0.0.1:3306             0.0.0.0:*
```

would be "combined" to give "127.0.0.1:3306 (mysql)" or something to that effect. I only know the above mapping because I googled what the default MySQL port is.

Is there a way to do this? It must be said that I am only learning to use these networking tools so any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't recall a command that does the exact thing you're asking about.  The map between the number `3306` and the descriptive string `mysql` has traditionally been kept in the `/etc/services` file.  (see the output of `grep mysql /etc/services`)  However, this won't help if a process has bound itself to a port that isn't in the `services` file.  For those cases something more like `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n` (invoked as the root user) can show the ports that are being listened to and by which programs/commands.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how `ss` resolves port numbers into service names. Is that through the `/etc/services` file like you  mentioned?

Comment: Note that those names are process names, not service names (they might or might not be the same). `/etc/services` will list `https` for port 443, but `ss` might list `nginx`, for example. If you want to use the `systemd` service name, that's another issue, you should say so in the question and maybe tag it with `systemd`. A single service could be handling more than one port (say, apache 80/443).

Comment: @SottoVoce This should be an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two standard library calls; `getservbyname(3)` and `getservbyport(3)`.  These allow programs to convert a name (e.g. `telnet`) to a port (23), or from a port back to a name.

The typical implementation uses `/etc/services` as the authoritative source, but this can be changed by the `services` entry in `nsswitch.conf`.

The command `getent` can be used to do some lookups, including service entries.

e.g. to convert from port to name

```
% getent services 80
http                  80/tcp www www-http
```

This tells me that port 80/tcp is mapped to "http" as the service name, but also has aliases "www" and "www-http".

Similarly to go from name to port

```
% getent services https       
https                 443/tcp
```

We can see https is on port 443/tcp.

These service names are just the registered values for these ports.  They don't correspond to *processes* (it could be apache, nginx, a python script...) and it doesn't guarantee the process uses these (eg apache could listen on port 12345 if configured to do so).

As far as I know, the standard `netstat` and `ss` commands will provide either names or ports, not both.  But you could write a simple program that took the output from `ss` and add the port->name mapping to each line.

Comment: It's worth noting that strictly speaking, this does not answer the question. It merely gives the canonical agreed upon port for a protocol, not the actual port a daemon is using. For example, if you configure MySQL to run on port 3305, `getent services mysql` will still return 3306. Similarly, if you run NGINX on port 80, `getent services nginx` will return nothing, because `nginx` is not a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common for a service to be configured to bind to a different port than the standard, so it might be more robust to `grep` for the process name you're looking for, for example:

`ss -lntpu | grep mysql`

Also works with `netstat`:

`netstat -lntpu | grep ssh`